# Getting next element text

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery I'm running to get the first < a > tag text, but it seems its getting all of the elements and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<tr>
<td>
    <a>text 1</a>
</td>
<td>
    <a>text 2</a>
</td>
<td>
    <a>text 3</a>
</td>
<td>
    <a>text 4</a>
</td>
<button>click</button>
</tr>

 $(button).on('click',function(){
     var getText = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('a:first-child');
     var getText = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('a:nth-child(1)');//tried this too
 })
```

So the result should be "text 1" for the variable. Right now its returning all < a > tags.

Comment: Can you add html code ?

Comment: sorry, forgot to indent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `a` tags are the first child of it's parent, so get the `a` tag within the first `td` element. And there is no need to use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method in case you want to get the `a` tag within the same `tr` element.

```
 var getText = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child a');
```

**FYI :** Your markup is not valid since you can't use `button` tag as the child within the `tr` tag, the only [allowed tags are `td` and `th`](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-tr-element). So move the `button` tag to any of the `td` or add a new `td` element.

Comment: ok this worked, when I can give you a checkmark i will thanks. Used first-child wrong.

Comment: @Anonymous :  yes it is :)

Answer (score 2):

First off, the button should be in a `<td>` as well, since it's no legitimate child of a `<tr>`.

Then, you want to find the table row. `closest(tr)` travels up the tree and finds that row.

You use `next()`, which will select the **next** row... but you don't want that. So delete it.

Then you want to find the **first** table cell and find the anchor inside the cell (so not the first anchor). We do that with `find(td:first-child a)`.

Last... with `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child a')` you get the object (element). If you want the **text** inside it, use the `text()`-function.

All together:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
   var getText = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child a').text();
   console.log(getText);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>text 1</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a>text 2</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a>text 3</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a>text 4</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `a:nth-of-type(1)` as selector problem will be solved
as

```
('a:nth-of-type(1)').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the foloowing:

```
$(button).on('click',function(){
     var getText = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:first a').html();
 });
```

Comment: This still gives all `a` elements, you need to `find('tr:first-of-type a);` first

Answer (score 0):

You have to add .text() function like below

```
$(button).on('click',function(){
 var getText = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('a:first-child').text();
 var getText = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('a:nth-child(1)').text();//tried this too
 })
```